# Sorting vectors with upper and lowercase letters

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, vector, stl

So I have a program that reads through a file and gets the largest words by using a `std::map` with an `int` as the key and a `std::vector` as value. I need to print out the largest words but have a problem with the sorting. Whereas the output should be Copyright, Publishin, Universal, blueprint 
I get :blueprint, Copyright, Universal, Publishin

How can I fix this? Do vectors not sort uppercase AND lowercase?
Here's what I have so far:

```
string temp;
stringstream ss(line);
while(ss >> temp) {
    int wordlength = temp.length();
    wordit = wordbycount.find(wordlength);
    if (wordit != wordbycount.end()) {
        vector<string> arrayofLongest = wordit->second; 
        std::vector<string>::iterator iterator1 = find(arrayofLongest.begin(), arrayofLongest.end(), temp);
        if (iterator1 == arrayofLongest.end()) {
            wordit->second.push_back(temp);
        }
    }
    else {
        wordbycount[wordlength] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: You might consider adding one more line to invoke std::sort() on your vector.

Answer (score 0):

> Do vectors not sort uppercase AND lowercase?

No.

`std::vector`s doesn't sort (simply appending elements).

`std::vector`s maintain the order of insertion.

If you want an insert-and-ordering container, you should use `std::set` (or `std::multiset`).